# Checking Chronometer Time from Another Class Shortcut

Tags: java, android, class, chronometer

I have a Chronometer in Class Apple.  I want to check what time the Chronometer is at in Class Banana.  I do not want to create a Chronometer in Class Banana, nor do I want to make an Apple Object in Class Banana.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Let me know if i can be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there more than one Apple in your (presumably) game?

If there is exactly one then you can make the chronometer a public static member of Apple and just read it from within your instance of Banana. Like this:

```
public class Banana {

 public void foo() {
   System.out.print(Apple.chronometer.printValue()); 
 }
}
```

If there are multiple Apple instances, then you need 1) put them into some sort container; 2) pass in, set, or construct your instance of Banana with a reference to that container; 3) Access the appropriate apple instance in the container, and read the chronometer's value, call its methods, etc. If the chronometer is a private member of Apple, you need to provide an accessor method so it can be accessed by code in your Banana instance.

Comment: there is only one Apple. i like where ur heads at! thanks!  Apple.chronometer.printValue() is not working tho. any ideas?

Comment: I just made up the printValue method. I don't know what your chronometer is exactly. An instance of a class? A long integer? Whatever "read its value" means, you will have to substitute in the right code. Making it a public static member of Apple, though will work.

Comment: ah got it. its a bit complicated, but i can figure it out from here. thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Make a getter for then Chronometer in class apple then from banana just call your getter

Apple:

`public Chronometer getMeter() {
    return mChronometer;
}`

Banana

`Chronometer meter = apple.getMeter();`

Comment: This would require creating an Apple Object in Class Banana.  I was hoping to not need to do that.